# Problem with greek letters in Computer Modern Unicode

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, greek, computer-modern

I've tried to use Computer Modern Unicode (version 0.7.0) with XeLaTeX to write greek letters.

However, using the following code in TeXLive 2012 or 2014, the shapes of "βγλθωχ" seem different with those provided in the document http://canopus.iacp.dvo.ru/~panov/cm-unicode/cmunrm.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}
βγλθωχ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bottom: greek letters provided in the document

But I got the shapes same with those in the document, using the following code with **polyglossia**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}
βγλθωχ
\end{document}
```

I cannot figure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This has nothing to do with small caps, by the way.

Comment: And [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436), and kudos for providing a very good [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that if your system is set in a Latin locale, then `fontspec` automatically sets `Script = Latin`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script = Latin]{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}
βγλθωχ
\end{document}
```

[image]

The font `CMU Serif` is designed so that it automatically substitutes certain Greek glyphs with more "Latin looking" glyphs if the script is set to Latin.

As seen below, exactly the glyphs in your example are those that are substituted. The names of the substitutions reveal why. They end in `.ipa`, indicating that they are to be used in [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA) transcriptions. This substitution is highly appropriate, and reveals a good font design. Greek glyphs in IPA transcriptions will be interspersed among Latin letters, and Greek glyphs in that context *should* look more "Latin like".

[image]

To prevent this substitution, you can simply set the script to Greek.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script = Greek]{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}
βγλθωχ
\end{document}
```

[image]

My conjecture is that you get the same effect by setting `\setmainlanguage{greek}` with `polyglossia` because this will automatically set `Script = Greek, Language = Greek` as `fontspec` options.

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, is the application shown in the answer FontForge?

Comment: @toubun Yes, it's FontForge.

Comment: Does this not work with `pdfTeX`?